# Writing hexadecimal in a proper way (in python)

Tags: python, hex

I have a binary file to read and i want to show the result in a proper form of hexadecimal.
The code as follows:

```
file=open('myfile.chn', 'rb')   
while 1:  

        b=fic.readline(1)
        print(b)
file.close()
```

and the result as follows :

```
b'\xff'  
b'\xff'  
b'\x01'  
b'\x00'  
.  
.
```

What can i do in order to change the result as follows :

```
FF  
FF  
01  
00  
.  
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"%02X" % ord(b'\xff')
```

will return the string `'FF'`.

Comment: and if i want to maintain the 0 in front of 1, how can i do? for example, i get 1 instead of 01.

Answer (score 2):

to meet your requirement of maintaining leading zeroes:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\x0f').decode().upper()
'0F'
```

also works with more than one byte in a row:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\xff\x01\x00\xaf').decode().upper()
'FF0100AF'
```